# Run PSQL command from bash script

Tags: postgresql, scripting, psql, bash

I would like to know how to run `\du` within a script, and output that to a file.

Something like the following:

```
# some_script.sh

psql <database connection> & \du > output_of_du.txt
```

I can find information about running `.sql` files via psql, but I can't find information about running psql commands themselves.

I found the following whilst searching:

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35347368/unable-to-run-psql-command-from-within-a-bash-script - about running SQL not a PSQL command
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54619776/cannot-get-psql-command-to-run-in-bash-script - seems to be about running a `.sql` script

But they're not what I'm after.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `-c` flag and combine it with `-L` to gather the output:

```
psql <database connection> -c \du -L output_of_du.txt
```

See psql-tip number 1 (https://psql-tips.org/psql_tips_all.html#tip001) and psql-tip number 26 (https://psql-tips.org/psql_tips_all.html#tip026)

Comment: Depending on the shell, the backslash will need to be itself escaped (\\du), or the whole argument quoted (‘\du’).

Comment: Woops, yes that's right